# What is Accessibility Capping?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading **C# 5.0 in a Nutshell**, and I found the concept **Accessibility Capping** as follows (original extract from the book):

[image: Accessibility Capping definition]

Can someone explains me this concept whith other example o different definition? With other words, what is its utility?

Comment: The last sentence in your screenshotted quote gives an example of its utility. Can you explain more clearly exactly what you don't understand?

Comment: @Blorgbeard , thanks. Can you explain me with your own words the utility found in the screenshot?

Comment: No, the screenshot is clear enough. I'm not playing a guessing game with you about what your question is.

Comment: Are you looking for an Eric Lippert type of metaphor with Tigers and Lions that explains it?  Or a further clarification specifically about accessibility in the C# language?  Have you read the language spec by the way?

Comment: I have never heard of this concept before reading the question and a quick internet search finds only this question and the book. It seems to be a concept invented by the author and I would not spend too much time delving into it (but of course you need to understand accessibility in C# if you want to learn the language).

Comment: @DeanOC offers me a clear and understandable answer for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is saying that because no accessibility has been declared for the class C, it is given the `internal` level as a default.

Therefore this means that even though C's Foo method is marked as `public`, it will be capped at `internal` because that's what the class's level is.

The reason why it is capped is that it makes no sense to have a class's member more accessible than the class itself, as anything requiring the accessibility level of the member will never see it because the class won't be available.

The last bit is saying that it can still be useful to have the property marked `public`, because if later on you make the class C `public`, then Foo will also be `public` (otherwise you would also have to change Foo from `internal` to `public`.)

I think the book is confusing because it is explaining 2 things at once, capping, and the fact that if you don't declare an accessibility level on a class then it gets `internal` by default.

IMHO, it would have been clearer to have

```
internal class MyClass
{
   public void Foo() {}
}
```

BTW, I also hate the fact that the class is called C. Was the guy trying to cut down on printing costs or something?